# Renaming files on upload by webform using field values in Appscript

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a basic receipt uploader for a non-profit. It is already functional and integrated to spreadsheets etc for data logging, I'm just trying to fix this one bit about renaming uploaded files.

The current code uploads file with the original filename, each into a folder that is named with a reference id. It is very hard to go through individual folders for each image.

I would like images posted to month folders, with the files renamed with input from the webform. Those are already stored as variables in the script so I can use them to build a string no problem. Variables in italics below

So the goal is to rename the uploaded image as
YEAR/MONTH/*ReferenceID*_*Name*_*Date*_*Category*_*Amount*_Category.extension

(should get the original file extension and keep that)

Thank you so much

```
function upload_receipt(
  transaction_id,
  data,
  file
)
{
  /*Uploads receipt to google drive.*/
  
  // Load receipt folder.
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id goes here");
  
  // Make new folder.
  new_folder = folder.createFolder(transaction_id)
  
  // Save file.
  var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
  bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
  blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file),
  file = new_folder.createFile(blob);

  return new_folder.getId();
}
```

the whole context

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('forms.html').setTitle("CCC Receipt Uploader");
}

function submitReceipt(
  data,
  file,
  vendor,
  contact_info,
  account,
  amount,
  date_transaction,
  description_of_expense,
  notes
)
{
  /*Main function to run after submitting receipt.
  
  This function 
   (1) Uploads the submitted receipt to google drive.
   (1) Adds entry to relevant finance sheet containing submitted metadata and reference to uploaded receipt.
  */
  console.log("account")
  console.log(account)

  try {

    // Get time of receipt submission.
    var date_submission = new Date();
    
    // Get new receipt id number.
    var transaction_id = get_transaction_id();
   
    // Upload receipt and get location.         
    var  receipt_location = upload_receipt(transaction_id, data, file)

    // amount should be negative
    amount = -1 * amount
    
    // Add metadata and receipt to finance sheet.
    add_item_to_expense_sheet(
      transaction_id,
      date_submission,
      date_transaction,
      vendor,
      contact_info,
      amount,
      account,
      description_of_expense,
      notes,
      receipt_location
    );
 
    return ["OK", transaction_id];
    
  } catch (f) {
    return f.toString();
  }
  
}


function upload_receipt(
  transaction_id,
  data,
  file
)
{
  /*Uploads receipt to google drive.*/
  
  // Load receipt folder.
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('obscuredid');
  
  // Make new folder.
  new_folder = folder.createFolder(transaction_id)
  
  // Save file.
  var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
  bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
  blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file),
  file = new_folder.createFile(blob);

  return new_folder.getId();
}


function add_item_to_expense_sheet(
  transaction_id,
  date_submission,
  date_transaction,
  external_account,
  contact_info,
  amount,
  internal_account,
  description_of_expense,
  notes,
  receipt_location
) {  
  /*Adds new entry to expense sheet.*/
  
  // Stupid way of filling out entire row of sheet.
  var account_category = "UNKNOWN";
  var status = "incomplete";
  var notes = "vendor contact: " + contact_info + "\n" + notes
  
  // New row to be input.
  var new_data = [ 
    transaction_id, 
    date_submission, 
    date_transaction, 
    status,
    internal_account, 
    account_category,
    amount,
    external_account,
    description_of_expense,
    receipt_location,
    notes
    ];
  
  // Open budget sheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('obscuredid');
 
  // Get relevant sheet.
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("house_invoices");
  
  // Set data.
  sheet.appendRow(new_data)
}


function get_transaction_id() {
  /*Ggenerates next transaction id.
  
  NOTE: Currently this function reads from a document containing the current transaction
  number and then increments by 1. This is obviously very fragile.
  */
  
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('obscuredid');
  
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  var paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();
  
  var current_reference_number = paragraphs[1].getText();
  
  var newnumber = parseInt(current_reference_number,10)+1
  
  var newnumber_str = pad(newnumber,6);
  
  var text = paragraphs[1].editAsText();
  
  text.deleteText(0,5);
  
  text.appendText(newnumber_str)
  
  return newnumber_str
  
}


function pad(num, size) {
    var s = "000000000" + num;
    return s.substr(s.length-size);
}

function getScriptURL() {
  return ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample spreadsheet with dummy values, and show your current output and expected output so that we can further help with your question?

Comment: I don't need help on the spreadsheet side, I'm just trying to do the save a file with the filename above. The values that I have available in the script, as variables, are  below.

data,
  file,
  vendor,
  contact_info,
  account,
  amount,
  date_transaction,
  description_of_expense,
  notes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function upload_receipt(transaction_id, data, file) {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id goes here");
  const fs = folder.getFolders();
  let fnsA = [];
  while (fs.hasNext()) { fnsA.push(fs.next().getName()) };
  const fn = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy/MMM");
  if (!~fnsA.indexOf(fn)) { var new_folder = folder.createFolder(fn);}
  const contentType = data.substring(5, data.indexOf(';'));
  const bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,') + 7));
  const blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file);
  const newfile = new_folder.createFile(blob);
  return newfile.getId();
}
```

Comment: That does the same thing as above though. I was asking about 2 things
1) How to rename the file
2) How to make it go into Month / Date folders (check if folder exists, make it if not,)

Comment: could you help me rename the file itself as well?

Comment: I don't know anything abut the data structure in the event object.  I don't know where the files are found nor where any of the values you with rename the files are.  Also please note I will not follow links to spreadsheets.  If you wish my help you must put it into the question in a way that I can copy and paste it.

Comment: thank you, I added the whole serverside script in the original question